# Update view of multiple tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a view (VW_Users) that connects to multiple tables (Users, Users_Data), one of these tables has a column called "Sent" ("Users" table)
I want to mark it as true

```
public async Task<bool> MarkSent()
{
    try
    {
        using (DBContext DBContext = new DBContext(this._ServerName, this._DBname))
        {
            var userRecords = await DBContext.VW_Users.ToListAsync();
            if (userRecords.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var user in userRecords)
                {
                    user.Sent = true;
                }
                await DBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work and does not update the column "Sent", however if I try to do the same but change the userRecords to

```
var userRecords = await DBContext.Users.ToListAsync();
```

It works well, so my guess is the DBContext cannot update the view but can only update a table directly, however I thought the view is considered one table at the end of things so i'm not sure why this wouldn't work.

Comment: A `VIEW` is *not* a `TABLE`, no; it doesn't store any data. A `VIEW` is simply a predefined `SELECT`, which can be referenced like a `TABLE`. `VIEW`s *can* have DML statements run against them, however, how these behave varies depending on if the `VIEW` is "updatable" or not; if it isn't updatable then `INSERT OF` triggers need to be used. Without the definition of the view, it's impossible to know what behaviour would occur.

Comment: @ThomA If I try to update the view with an UPDATE SQL statement it works well

Comment: That comment conflict with what you state in your question, which states it *isn't* working.

Comment: @ThomA it actually doesn't as I said the issue is with using DBContext to update a view, regular SqlCommand using UPDATE statement to the view or just running an UPDATE statement in SQL Server Studio works on the view, however when running this piece of code using DBContext it doesn't seem to update it.